# Rendering array pictures from calling API in react.js

Tags: api, reactjs

I have API which consists

```
 "pictures": [
  "http:\/\/storage\/web\/source\/images\/2016-10-28\/edac054f88fd16aee7bc144545fea4b2.jpg",
  "http:\/\/storage\/web\/source\/images\/2016-10-28\/9aa3217f37f714678d758de6f7f5222d.jpg",
  "http:\/\/storage\/web\/source\/images\/2016-10-28\/5164ed92c205dc73a37d77e43fe1a284.jpg"
]
```

I have to render these pictures in Carousel. The problem is I have no idea how to render that pictures from an array, means that each picture should be outputted in each slider separately.

That is my code:

```js
const API = 'http://...';

export default class Api extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      slider_pics:[
        
      ],
    }
  }
  fetchProfile(id) { 
    let url = `${API}${name}`;
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json() )
      .then((data) => {   
        this.setState({
          slider_pics:data.data.pictures,
          
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error) )
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchProfile(this.state.name);
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div> 
      <div>
            <Carousel data={this.state}/>
      </div>
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```js
export default class Carousel extends React.Component {
    render() {
         let data = this.props.data;
      return(
        <div>
          <React_Boostrap_Carousel animation={true} className="carousel-fade">
            <div >
              <img style={{height:500,width:"100%"}} src={data.slider_pics} />
            </div>
            <div style={{height:500,width:"100%",backgroundColor:"aqua"}}>
              456
            </div>
            <div style={{height:500,width:"100%",backgroundColor:"lightpink"}}>
              789
            </div>
          </React_Boostrap_Carousel>
        </div>
      )
    }
};
```

In this code all the URL images are rendering in one slide, I need each picture renders separately in each slide. Please help.

Comment: Well you are setting an array of images as the img src. You'll have to loop through the images and render an `img` element for each of the images separately.

Comment: I need to use map for looping and where i have to make a loop in Api component or Carousel? Pls, if it is not hard for u could u give me example, how would be better to loop pics using api?

Comment: `export default class Carousel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      const slider_pics=[];
       
       for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         slider_pics.push();
    }
     this.state = { slider_pics };    
  }
    render() {
         let data = this.props.data;
      return(
        <div>
          <React_Boostrap_Carousel animation={true} className="carousel-fade">
            <div >
              {this.state.slider_pics.map((slider_pic, index) => (
                <img src={slider_pic} />
              ))}
            </div>`

Comment: I updated code like this could u pls have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I almost figured out on my own. In Carousel component we have to set the loop in constructor and return that loop in map. Shortly, this is my code that is working for 100%

```js
export default class Carousel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      const slider_pics=[];  
       for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         slider_pics.push(<React_Boostrap_Carousel />);
    }
     this.state = {slider_pics};    
  }
    render() {
         let data = this.props.data;
      return(
        <div>
          <React_Boostrap_Carousel animation={true} className="carousel-fade">
              {data.slider_pics.map((slider_pic, index) => (
                <div  key={index}>
                <img  style={{heght:200, width:1000}} src={slider_pic} />
                </div>
              ))}
          </React_Boostrap_Carousel>
        </div>
      )
    }
};
```

The API component will be the same, just need to update the Carousel component like code above