# Rendering Component in Carousel using React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, materialize, axios

I want to achieve a carousel like [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html).
Have an API from where I am fetching the data, so according to Materialize

### I compared the console or Materialize default and my rendered components.

I guess the problem is, it's not inheriting the properties of `carousel-item`

---

Class `carousel-item` is supposed to Render inside of Class `carousel`.

```
<div className="carousel">
// These are supposed to be dynamic, below component is not present here
  <div className="carousel-item">
  </div>
</div>
```

How I am trying to render the data is in this manner.

```
    renderAlbums(){
      return this.state.albums.map(album =>
          <Card song={album.name} singer={album.artist_name} src={album.cover_photo_url}/>
      );
    }
```

Rendered the data `<Card />`(It contains the class of `carousel-item`), which is supposed to place Card containing class of `carousel-item`.

```
class Carousel extends Component {
    state = { albums: [] };
    componentWillMount() {
      axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://stg-resque.hakuapp.com/albums.json')
        .then(response => this.setState({albums: response.data}));
    }
    renderAlbums(){
      return this.state.albums.map(album =>
          <div className="carousel-item"><Card key={album.name} song={album.name} singer={album.artist_name} src={album.cover_photo_url}/></div>
      );
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="carousel center">
          {this.renderAlbums()}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Carousel;
```

This is my Card component

```
class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

        <div className="card z-depth-4">
          <div>
            <img src={this.props.src} />
          </div>
          <p>{this.props.song}</p>

          <div className="singer">{this.props.singer}</div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Card;
```

**EDIT:**

- [Want that content to display like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj3ym.png)

But it's not working the way it's expected.
Please suggest me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you initiated the carousel as document says by calling $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.carousel').carousel();
    });  ??

Comment: Ohh yes, I did that. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it's not working the way it's expected"? Are there any warning messages? Is the `renderAlbums()` function is properly bound to the class instance? When you call `array.map()` to generate the components array, make sure to pass a unique `key` prop to the components.

Comment: [It looks like this right now](https://imgur.com/a/I9Gbp), it's taking the class, but it's not displaying.

Comment: @HemantMetallia Something must be wrong with your setup then. If you look at the style for `carousel-item` it is still set to `display: none`. That's why you're not seeing it. Makes me think the carousel package isn't being used correctly. You need to post more code if you want more help. Post your entire `Carousel` and `Card` components.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda, please check the edit.

Comment: @HemantMetallia I don't see this piece of code anywhere: `$(document).ready(function(){ $('.carousel').carousel(); });` You have to initialize the jQuery plugin for it to work.

Comment: It should be in `componentDidMount` of your `Carousel` component.

Comment: So I should add `renderAlbums` in `componentDidMount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `axios.get`, I see that you are using proxy link.

One reason is, it can be creating problems.

---

Other reason can be you are trying to put `carousel-item` into `carousel`.
Try adding `center` class to both i.e. `carousel` as well as `carousel-item`.

Check if these works.

Comment: Let me check the API first.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is nothing in your Carousel that says which element is active. You need to have a state variable that points to the active element.

Then you only need to draw [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2] offsets vs the active one. And each rendered card needs to know which offset to know their style.

Comment: materialize does everything for you, I assume.

Comment: [Render Pics Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341936/rendering-array-pictures-from-calling-api-in-react-js), can this be any useful?